# Word order and auxiliary verbs in questions (present simple tense)

Tags: word-order, questions, auxiliary-verbs, present-simple

I'm using an app to learn/practice English and I had a task to translate a question into English.

My answer was:

> May I know why exactly does he think so?

But the app said that it was incorrect and the correct answer was:

> May I know why exactly he thinks so?

Can anybody, please, explain to me why my answer is wrong and the answer with no auxiliary verb is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were asking the question directly, it would be "Why does he think so?"

However, if you add another phrase in interrogative form to ask the question indirectly (which is more polite), you *don't* use the question form for the thing you want to know.

> *May I know* why he thinks so?
>
> *Can you tell me* what time it is?